# How to check version of Oracle Provider for OLE DB

Tags: oracle11g, oledb

How can I check what version of OLE DB Provider - Oracle Provider for OLE DB I am using ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below will get you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT instance_name, host_name, version
FROM V$INSTANCE
;
```

Another oracle variable I find useful sometimes is:

```
SELECT ora_database_name FROM dual;
```

The above two examples are within a group of variables called Synonyms.  To view a full list of the synonyms available for use you can query these out by looking at the DBA_SYNONYMS view.

```
SELECT synonym_name, table_owner, table_name
FROM DBA_SYNONYMS
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the dll (OraOLEDBXX.DLL), the 'XX' will be the version.
[image: Right click in the dll]